# Existence of unique weak solution of elliptic type equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am given the PDE problem:
\begin{cases} - \sum\limits_{i, j=1}^n\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \bigg(a_{ij}\frac{\partial u }{\partial x_j} \bigg)-cu=f & \text{on $\Omega$} \\ 
u=0 & \text{on $\partial\Omega$}\end{cases}

where $f\in L^2 (\Omega) $ and $a_{ij}(x) \in L^\infty(\Omega) $ for bounded open subset $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, assume that for some constant $c_0>0$, we have
$$\sum_{i, j=1}^N a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\ge c_0|\xi|^2, \quad  \xi \in \mathbb{R} ^N.$$

**How can I prove the below claim?**

The PDE has unique weak solution provided that $$c_0>c \cdot \inf_{u\in C^1_0(\Omega) } \frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 } {\int_\Omega |u|^2}. $$

Comment: 1. Can you explain what you have tried so far in solving the problem? 

2. Could you correct your title? This is a more general elliptic PDE, not the Poisson equation. For Poisson, you need $a_{ij}=0,$ if $i \neq j,$ $a_{ii}=1$ and $c=0.$ 

3. I suspect that in your problem setting, you wanted the partial derivatives in the sum to be taking wrt different variables $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}$.

Answer (score 2):

The standard technique here is the [Lax-Milgram Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babu%C5%A1ka%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem). Let $B: H^1_0(\Omega)\times H^1_0(\Omega)\to \mathbb R$ be given by $$B(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j}-cuv \, dx. $$

Given $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, recall that a weak solution to your PDE is a function $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $B(u,v) = (f,v)_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega).$ Such a solution is guaranteed by the Lax-Mligram theorem provided that we show:

1. $B$ is bounded, that is, $\vert B(u,v) \vert\leq C \| u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \|v\| _{H^1(\Omega)} $ for all $u,v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
2. $B$ is coercive, that is, $B(u,u) \geq C \| u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2$.

I’ll leave you to check boundedness. For coercivity, \begin{align*}
B(u,u)&= \int_{\Omega}a_{ij}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}-cu^2 \, dx \\
&\geq c_0 \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u\vert^2 \, dx - \int_\Omega cu^2 \, dx
\end{align*} by ellipticity. Now, assume that $$ c < c_0 \inf_{\stackrel{u\in H^1_0(\Omega)}{u\neq 0}} \bigg \{ \frac{\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx}{\int_\Omega u^2 \, dx}\bigg \} $$ (which I believe is what you meant to write). Then there exists some $\mu \in (0,1)$ such that $$ c \leq \mu c_0 \inf_{\stackrel{u\in H^1_0(\Omega)}{u\neq 0}} \bigg \{ \frac{\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx}{\int_\Omega u^2 \, dx}\bigg \},$$  so \begin{align*}
B(u,u)&\geq c_0 \bigg (  \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u\vert^2 \, dx - \mu \inf_{\stackrel{u\in H^1_0(\Omega)}{u\neq 0}} \bigg \{ \frac{\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx}{\int_\Omega u^2 \, dx} \bigg \} \int_\Omega u^2 \, dx \bigg ) \\
&\geq c_0(1-\mu) \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u\vert^2 \, dx .
\end{align*} Then an application of the Poincaré inequality implies that $B$ is coercive which, in turn, gives the existence of a unique weak solution.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

$$ \vec \xi^T \cdot a \cdot\vec \xi > c_0 |\vec \xi|^2$$

means, that the symbol of the second order differential operator $\nabla A \nabla$ is bounded   away from zero by the standard Laplacian with symbol   $\text{smb}(\nabla \nabla)= | \vec \xi |^2$.

The production term of $u$ has to by small enough everwhere locally, such that the transport of the quantity generated at local sources to the boundary is possible per time step  (electrically: current source obeys Ohms law), such that in a diffusion process $\partial_t f -\nabla A \nabla f =u  $ a stationary state will evolve for $t \to \infty$, independent of the start configuration.